# How to avoid Jenkins SVN checkout giving error E210003?

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins, ssh-tunnel, svn-checkout

I want to check out two projects from svn with one job in Jenkins.

[image: SVN checkouts]

I have removed potentially sensitive business information from the screenshots.

I open up an SVN tunnel before checking out the projects. This is working as expected.

The first project is checked out as expected but the second one is not.

I get the following SVNException: `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210003: connection refused by the server`

[image: SVNException]

I've tried to search the Internet for solutions but to no avail. Searching the error message only gives limited results.

What I don't understand is why the first project is succesfully checked out but the second one fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projects contain a lot of data, which resulted in the svn checkout process to take too long. This caused a time-out on the SSH tunnel that is opened before performing the svn checkouts.

I set the duration before the time-out to a larger number which solved my problem.